# Do all algabraic recursive functions have an equivalent non-recursive closed form function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, recursion

Given that we have a recursive function defined as

$\begin{matrix}
f_{0}=0
\\ 
f_{n}=f_{n-1}+1
\end{matrix}$

We can come up with a related non-recursive closed form function defined as

$g(x)=x$

Where for every value of $n$

$f_{n}=g(n)$

Do all recursive functions defined with

$\begin{matrix}
f_{0}=\text{an integer}
\\ 
f_{n}=\text{an algebraic function(1)}
\end{matrix}$

(1): where said function involves only algebraic operations, like, addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, as well as fractional or rational exponents

have such a related non-recursive closed form function $g(x)$?

I'm not looking for how to find $g(x)$ if it exists, I`m just wondering if one always exists.

Comment: How are you defining 'algebraic function' in this context? Perhaps $f_0 = 1$, $f_{n+1} = 2^{f_n}$, so that $f_n = {}^n2$ would show you that the answer is 'no' if tetration isn't considered algebraic.

Comment: I don't think you really mean "[algebraic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function)".  For example, the recurrence $f_0 = 1$, $f_{n+1} = 2 f_n$ has solution $f_n = 2^n$ which is not an algebraic function.  If you mean "closed form", it is actually quite rare for a nonlinear recurrence to have a closed form.

Comment: I will update question

Comment: question re-specified, I did not know of closed form functions but that better fits what I'm trying to convey anyway